# pagemethods overwrite values

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have class define static variables, it works fine, but when different people are logged in the value is overwritten.
like if I am logged in as user1 and i select LocationFrom = 3 it works fine but when user2 log in and he select locationFrom = 2, then on different PC and browser my LocationFrom is also set to 2, when i refresh my page user1 and user2 both locationFrom is set to 3, following is sample from my code

```
public partial class ABC: System.Web.UI.Page
{
  static string LoacationFrom;
  static string LocationTo;

  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void locatFrom(string LocFrom)
  {
    LoacationFrom = LocFrom;
  }
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public static void LocatTo(string LocTo)
  {
    LocationTo = LocTo;
  }

  protected void ExecuteReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: these pagemethods are called from telerik controls radcomobox to avoid `autopost` back

Comment: Who calls the page method doesn't matter, you have a concurrency problem on shared resources. Consider using Session, ViewState or other flags that are tied to your current user.